# roswtf static check error: "Local network configuration is invalid"

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, roswtf, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`roswtf` complains, but `ping` resolves by passing hostname that roswtf failed checking. While it's possible that my computer's network is not configured in a normal way (although I don't remember I had to do anything unusual), is there a chance `roswtf` doing anything wrong?

```
term-1$ roscore

term-2$ roswtf
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR Local network configuration is invalid: Local hostname [myhostname] resolves to [xxxx:204:mmmm:2f40:nnnn:13ab:a569:9968%2,xxxx:204:mmmm:2f40:fdca:ff2e:8f90:7f28%3,fe80::7ad:7736:630f:7461%enp0s31f6,fe80::5b54:45f3:d998:14b9%wlp4s0,xxxx:204:mmmm:2f40:ee5:e220:744e:2329%2,fe80::42:7ff:fedd:872e%docker0], which does not appear to be a local IP address ['127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.16', '192.168.0.39', '172.17.0.1'].

$ ping myhostname
PING myhostname (192.168.0.16) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 130s-p50 (192.168.0.16): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from 130s-p50 (192.168.0.16): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms

$ ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:07:dd:87:2e  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:7ff:fedd:872e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:150800 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:254540 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:9119181 (9.1 MB)  TX bytes:384850257 (384.8 MB)

enp0s31f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:5b:76:6a:61:39  
          inet addr:192.168.0.16  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7ad:7736:630f:7461/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: xxxx:204:mmmm:2f40:nnnn:13ab:a569:9968/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: xxxx:204:mmmm:2f40:ee5:e220:744e:2329/64 Scope:Global
          :

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1597169 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1597169 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:160806226 (160.8 MB)  TX bytes:160806226 (160.8 MB)

wlp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e4:a4:71:e5:e9:2b  
          inet addr:192.168.0.39  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: xxxx:204:mmmm:2f40:fdca:ff2e:8f90:7f28/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::5b54:45f3:d998:14b9/64 Scope:Link
          :

$ rospack find roswtf
/opt/ros/kinetic/share/roswtf
$ rosversion roswtf
1.12.13
$ apt-cache policy ros-kinetic-roswtf
ros-kinetic-roswtf:
  Installed: 1.12.13-0xenial-20180222-233556-0800
  Candidate: 1.12.13-0xenial-20180222-233556-0800
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291485/roswtf-static-check-error:-%22local-network-configuration-is-invalid%22/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2018-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your network / host has IPv6 enabled, which is not properly supported (last time I checked) by `roswtf` (and some other ROS tools). The resolver that `roswtf` (Python) uses returns the IPv6 addresses first, so `roswtf` doesn't see the IPv4 addresses. It then complains.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-05-19**:
Confirmed that turning off ipv6 allows `roswtf` to not return error. But why does it return error with ipv6 on? [Asked](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1403) if that's what roswtf is supposed to do.

**Comment by [nsdolic](https://answers.ros.org/users/39371/nsdolic/) on 2019-03-06**:
I am getting the same error. Trying to determine if this might be causing an issue with transform timeout error. Does anyone know what problems this error might cause?